# Workflow triggered on replication event listener looping itself in AEM

Tags: java, workflow, aem

I have a workflow in AEM 6.5 that is triggered from java code on replication event listener, but the issue is my workflow has a process step which activates page after review from participant step. This activation again calls my workflow since its a replication event. How to prevent this? Is there a better approach or any workaround?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error.log file. If an error/exception occurred, AEM workflows would be run repeatedly. As a best practise, once the execution is finished, terminate the workflow in finally block.